# Unable to capture screenshots with new xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

After upgrading the latest version of my Mac pro I opened the Xcode organizer and notice that I am not able to capture any screenshots any more. Clicking on the "Take Screenshot" just doesn't do anything... Does someone have the same issue? 
I notice that there are plenty issues with the new upgrade, Can you try to think of a workaround?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode 6 -> Organizer, Device screenshots will be saved in Desktop.

Comment: Thanks! Too many windows prevent me from seeing the images... Do you know how can I change the save location?